# FutureOrPresent not working as expected with present date

Tags: java, jackson, localdate

Facing this issue as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66816134/futureorpresent-validator-some-times-violated-even-if-the-given-date-is-present). `@FutureOrPresent` doesn't let present date pass through.

```
@FutureOrPresent(message = "From Date Must Be Of Future Or Present")
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyCustomDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSerializer.class)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern= "dd-MM-yyyy", timezone ="UTC")
```

```
public class MyCustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Instant> {
    private DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    @Override
    public Instant deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(p.getText(), fmt);
        Instant instant = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant();
        return instant;
    }
}
```

```
public class MyCustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Instant> {
    private DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    @Override
    public void serialize(Instant value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String str = fmt.format(value);

        gen.writeString(str);
    }
```

I get this error:
`"errorCode": "BAD_REQUEST", "message": "From Date Must Be Of Future Or Present",`

Pojo field has future or present validation but present is not getting applied as expected. Can someone please help understanding the issue?

Comment: If there is an enough big interval between the date memorized in your request and the date of reception this would explain your issue.

Comment: Any workaround for this issue? @dariosicily